# onPostExecute doesn't get called

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

I have the following code to execute a PHP script:

```
public class CallPHPScript extends AsyncTask<ScriptNameAndParameters, Void, String> {
    private Reply responder;

    public interface Reply {
        public void serverReply(String reply);
    }

    public CallPHPScript(Reply r) {
        responder = r;
    }

    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(ScriptNameAndParameters... arg) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = arg[0].getParameters();
        String scriptName = arg[0].getScriptName();
        String json = MainActivity.makeCall(scriptName, params);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("SERVER REPLY", "Server Reply: " + result);
        responder.serverReply(result);
    }

}

public static String makeCall(String scriptName, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    String address = SERVER_ADDRESS + scriptName + ".php";

    Log.d("Main Activity", "Making call to server with: " + address);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = "";
        // Read response until the end
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }

        // Return full string
        Log.d("CALLPHPSCRIPT", total.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return total.toString();
}
```

While it seems to work ok, the only output I can see is

```
        // Return full string
        Log.d("CALLPHPSCRIPT", total.toString())
```

This line (and therefore my callback)

```
    Log.d("SERVER REPLY", "Server Reply: " + result);
```

never get called. Does anybody have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I'm supposed to call

```
    CallPHPScript callPHP = new CallPHPScript(this);
    callPHP.execute(new ScriptNameAndParameters("get_all_profiles",new ArrayList<NameValuePair>()));
```

instead of

```
    CallPHPScript callPHP = new CallPHPScript(this);
    callPHP.doInBackground(new ScriptNameAndParameters("get_all_profiles",new ArrayList<NameValuePair>()));
```

Doh!

Comment: well it's good when you found out :) just accept it as an answer, may help others!

Answer (score 1):

Since you solved the problem, you violated the Threading Rule of `AsyncTask` which is #3

Here's the [Threading rules](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to work the class properly

1. The `AsyncTask` class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done
   automatically as of `JELLY_BEAN`.
2. The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
           execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
3. Do not call `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute(Result)`,
   `doInBackground(Params...)`, `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` manually.
4. The task can be executed only once **(an exception will be thrown if a
           second execution is attempted.)**

Answer (score 0):

(/)

remember to gracefully close the connection manager and all input streams

```
    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

There is no need to call super in

```
super.onPostExecute(result);
```